# Django: Url can't be resolved

Tags: python, django, search

I've made an Application containing List of trainers. My Index View Displays these trainer profiles from the database. I intend to implement a sear bar to filter these results. I am not getting what i'm doing wrong. As soon as i mention the url in action of the search for, it displays reverse match error

url's.py :

```
       #/trainer/
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),

#/trainer/<trainer_id>/
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.DetailView.as_view(),name='details'),

#/trainer/trainer/add
url(r'trainer/add/$', views.TrainerCreate.as_view(), name='Trainer-add'),

#/trainer/trainer/<album_id>
url(r'trainer/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.TrainerUpdate.as_view(), name='Trainer-update'),

#/trainer/trainer/add
url(r'trainer/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.TrainerDelete.as_view(), name='Trainer-delete'),


url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='Search'),
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET['q']
    trainer= Trainer.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
    return render(request,'trainer/index.html', {'trainer': trainer})
```

search form in my base template

```
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="get" action="{% url 'trainer:Search' %}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="searchBox" class="input-medium search-query" name="q" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
    </form>
```

index.py

```
    <table style="width:100%" class="table table-hover">
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Technology</th>
                                <th>Location</th>
                            </tr>
                            {% for trainer in all_trainers %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="trainer{{ forloop.counter }}" name="trainer" value="{{ trainer.id }}"></td>
                                    <td> <a href="{% url 'trainer:details' trainer.id %}"> {{ trainer.name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ trainer.technology }}</td></a>

                                    <!-- View Details -->
                                    <td><a href="{% url 'trainer:details' trainer.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View Details</a></td>

                                    <td><a href="../media/{{ trainer.trainer_profile }}" class="btn">Download PDF</a></td>

                                    <!-- Delete Album -->
                                    <td>
                                        <form action="{% url 'trainer:Trainer-delete' trainer.id %}" method="post">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <input type="hidden" name="trainer_id" value="{{ trainer.id }}" />
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                        </button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </table>
```

Comment: You're problem is not that "search is not working" but that your url is not resolved. You should edit your post title...

Comment: okay.. so do u have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="get" action="{% url 'trainer:Search' %}">
```

to

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="get" action="{% url 'Search' %}">
```

Comment: Tried this. Still showing this error: NoReverseMatch at /trainer/

Comment: post the template  that you are using for /trainer/ url

Comment: post your template for IndexView and also the view code

Comment: add it to the question and not in comment

Comment: Ya ive added my index .py template. Though my search box in in my base.html which i've already added in the question

Comment: Remove all those trainer: from all the templates you dont need those just keep details or the names of the views

Comment: removing them and keeping the form from my answer will remove your problem

Comment: thanks . Its not searching correctly but atleast the url is showing. Ill work on where the search error is now !!

Comment: glad could help @GajalAgarwala

Answer (score 1):

You need `{% url 'Search' %}` and not `{% url 'trainer:Search' %}`; the `:` is for when you have [namespaced your urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces).

Comment: Tried this. Still showing this error:
NoReverseMatch at /trainer/

Comment: Did you restart the server? Can you please post the entire, complete error message in your question?

Comment: Ya i did restart. Not working:   
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'Search' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: Edit the question and post your complete `urls.py`

Comment: #/trainer/
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),
    #/trainer/<trainer_id>/
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.DetailView.as_view(),name='details'),
    #/trainer/album/add
    url(r'trainer/add/$', views.TrainerCreate.as_view(), name='Trainer-add'),

#/trainer/album/add
    url(r'trainer/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.TrainerDelete.as_view(), name='Trainer-delete'),
    url(r'trainer/search/$', views.search, name='Search'),

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45208849/edit) and add it there, so I can read it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the urls.py somewhere?

Otherwise you need to add caret ^ at the start of your regex.

```
url(r'^trainer/search/$', views.search, name='Search'),
```

Comment: yeah obviously im including it in the main url. Rest all are working.